# Does pam_cifscreds module work with sudo access?

Tags: linux, sudo, cifs, pam

I have an RHEL (7.9) server with a remote drive mounted as a multiuser CIFS volume. With multiuser CIFS shares, users need to execute an additional command (`cifscreds add`) in order to access it. This basically stores the user's password in the Linux keyring.

I found and implemented a solution to do this (initiate the keyring and store the password when the user logs in via SSH into the server. This is done through the pam_cifscreds module. Following lines were added to /etc/pam.d/sshd to get it to work:

```
auth        optional       pam_cifscreds.so     
.
.
session    required     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    required     pam_cifscreds.so        domain=XYZ 
.
.
```

It is working fine when the user SSH's in the server. They are able to access the mount without running the aforementioned command explicitly.

Now I have another scenario :
User logs in with the superuser, and sudo to the person user: for e.g., log in using root and sudo to 'user123'. In this case, user123 should be able to access the CIFS share.

I tried to add the same lines into /etc/pam.d/sudo and /etc/pam.d/su - but it does not work.
Logs from /var/log/secure indicate that the pam module is unable to find the password for user123.

Can someone please advise if it is possible to use pam_cifscreds with sudo access

Answer (score 0):

This cannot possibly work, because neither `su` nor `sudo` **know the password** of user123, so they aren't able to provide it to the PAM modules. (When called as root, the authentication step is skipped completely.)

You will need to continue using `cifscreds add` after entering user123's shell.

Use `keyctl show` to confirm that the keyring has been set up and that it has the correct entries.